# Flutter: How to make ListView to occupy available parent height

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm getting error after showing `ListView`. What I want to achieve is 'PlacesControls' widget is fixed size and rest of it should occupy remaining space below. So I wrapped my `ListView` with `Expanded` to achieve that but now I'm getting this error.

Error: `The ParentDataWidget Expanded(flex: 1) wants to apply ParentData of type FlexParentData to a RenderObject, which has been set up to accept ParentData of incompatible type BoxParentData.`

Page:

```
BlocProvider<PlacesBloc> buildBody(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocProvider(
      builder: (_) => sl<PlacesBloc>(),
      child: Center(
        child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
            child: Expanded(
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  // Top view
                  SizedBox(height: 20),
                  PlacesControls(),
                  // Bottom view
                  BlocBuilder<PlacesBloc, PlacesState>(
                    builder: (context, state) {
                      if (state is Empty) {
                        return MessageDisplay(
                          message: 'Search places around you!',
                        );
                      } else if (state is Loading) {
                        return LoadingWidget();
                      } else if (state is Loaded) {
                        return PlacesDisplay(places: state.places);
                      } else if (state is Error) {
                        return MessageDisplay(
                          message: state.message,
                        );
                      }
                    },
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            )),
      ),
    );
  }
```

`PlacesDisplay - ListView':

```
class PlacesDisplay extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<Place> places;

  const PlacesDisplay({
    Key key,
    @required this.places,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Expanded(
          child: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: places.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return ListTile(title: Text(places[index].name));
              })),
    );
  }
}
```

Here is layout expectation design Green widget height should be dynamic according to parent window height (its ListView so should be also scrollable):

[image]

Comment: shouldn't the expanded be around the places display only? `return Expanded(child: PlacesDisplay(places: state.places));`

Comment: Hey Martin, you can `upvote` the answer as well, I will appreciate that. That'd help me too. Thanks :) I am glad that it worked out for you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changes required:

- Return with `Expaned()` and wrap your `PlacesDisplay`
- `mainAxissize: MainAxisSize.min` should be there inside the `Page` `Column`
- Don't use `Expanded` to wrap your `Padding`. `Container` with `height` and `width` of device should be fine

**Page**

```
BlocProvider<PlacesBloc> buildBody(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocProvider(
      builder: (_) => sl<PlacesBloc>(),
      child: Center(
        child: Container( // <---- changed
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size:height, // <---- changed
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).of.width, // <---- changed
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
            child: Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min, // <---- changed
                children: <Widget>[
                  // Top view
                  SizedBox(height: 20),
                  PlacesControls(),
                  // Bottom view
                  BlocBuilder<PlacesBloc, PlacesState>(
                    builder: (context, state) {
                      if (state is Empty) {
                        return MessageDisplay(
                          message: 'Search places around you!',
                        );
                      } else if (state is Loading) {
                        return LoadingWidget();
                      } else if (state is Loaded) {
                        return Expanded(
                           child: PlacesDisplay(places: state.places)   // <--- changed
                        );
                      } else if (state is Error) {
                        return MessageDisplay(
                          message: state.message,
                        );
                      }
                    },
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ))
    );
  }
```

In your `PlacesDisplay`, simply return your `ListView.builder()`

**PlacesDisplay**

```
class PlacesDisplay extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<Place> places;

  const PlacesDisplay({
    Key key,
    @required this.places,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(   // <--- changed
       itemCount: places.length,
       itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return ListTile(title: Text(places[index].name));
       });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is because of the `Expanded` widget which you have used to wrap the `Column`. If you want the column to take up all the height, you should use `mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,` instead of wrapping it with an `Expanded`. `Expanded` widget should only be used inside a `Row`, `Column` or `Flex`.